# Print only the Nth line before each line that matches a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, search

I'm trying to print only the `<N>`th line before a search pattern. `grep -B<N>` prints all the `<N>` lines before the search pattern. I saw the awk code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185771/extract-nth-line-after-matching-pattern) that can print only the `<N>`th line after the search pattern.

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' file
```

How to modify this to print only the `<N>`th line before each line that matches `pattern` ? For example, here is my input file

```
...
...
   0.50007496  0.42473932  0.01527831
   0.99997456  0.97033575  0.44364198
Direct configuration=     1
   0.16929051  0.16544726  0.16608723
   0.16984300  0.16855274  0.50171112
...
...
   0.50089841  0.42608090  0.01499159
   0.99982054  0.97154975  0.44403547
Direct configuration=     2
   0.16931296  0.16553376  0.16600890
   0.16999941  0.16847055  0.50170694  
...
```

I need a command that can give me back the `2nd line` before the search string `Direct configuration`.
I'm trying to run this in ***SUSE-Linux***

Comment: Any reason you can't just `grep ... | head -1` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There are tens of thousands of occurence  of the search pattern in the file and I need only the Nth line before every  occurence

Comment: @thrig that would only return the first line, if you have more than one match they'll get pruned in the `head` execution.

Comment: How about `grep -B<N> ... | grep -A1 '^--$' | grep -v '^--$'`, to cut it down to only the first line of the resulting context?

Comment: The 'N lines after' version works by starting a counter when the match is seen, and printing when the count reaches 0.  To do 'N lines before', you'd have to save all of the last N lines somewhere, and print out the first of them when the match is seen.  It might be simpler to 'tac' the input file first.

Comment: @JigglyNaga that deserves to be an answer. `tac | awk ... |tac` should be just what the OP wants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A buffer of lines needs to be used.

Give a try to this:

```
awk -v N=4 -v pattern="example.*pattern" '{i=(1+(i%N));if (buffer[i]&& $0 ~ pattern) print buffer[i]; buffer[i]=$0;}' file
```

Set `N` value to the Nth line before the pattern to print.

Set `pattern`value to the regex to search.

`buffer` is an array of `N` elements. It is used to store the lines. Each time the pattern is found, the `N`th line before the pattern is printed.

Comment: @WanderingMind Then you should accept this answer. Especially since it uses `awk` as per your OP

Answer (score 8):

That code doesn't work for previous lines. To get lines before the matched pattern, you need to somehow save the lines already processed. Since `awk` only has associative arrays, I can't think of an equally simple way of doing what you want in `awk`, so here's a perl solution:

```
perl -ne 'push @lines,$_; print $lines[0] if /PAT/; shift(@lines) if $.>LIM;' file
```

Change `PAT` to the pattern you want to match and `LIM` to the number of lines. For example, to print the 5th line before each occurrence of `foo`, you would run:

```
perl -ne 'push @lines,$_; print $lines[0] if /foo/; shift(@lines) if $.>5;' file
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -ne` : read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `push @lines,$_` : add the current line (`$_`) to the array `@lines`.
- `print $lines[0] if /PAT/` : print the first element in the array `@lines` (`$lines[0]`) if the current line matches the desired pattern.
- `shift(@lines) if $.>LIM;` : `$.` is the current line number. If that is greater than the limit, remove the 1st value from the array `@lines`. The result is that `@lines` will always have the last `LIM` lines.

Comment: @WanderingMind yes, sorry, my bad. Perl usually assumes `$_` when nothing is given but apparently that's not the case for `push`. I was using it when testing and then removed it for the answer to make it shorter. I should have tested the shorter version.

Comment: @terdon `awk` does propose _classic_ arrays. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Jayjargot yes, I've already upvoted your answer, that's a neat trick. Those are still associative arrays though, it's just that you're using a number as an index. You still can't `push` or `pop` them.

Answer (score 4):

```
tac file | awk 'c&&!--c;/pattern/{c=N}' | tac
```

But this has the same omission as the 'forwards' use case when there are multiple matches within N lines of each other.

And it won't work so well when the input is piped from a running process, but it's the simplest way when the input file is complete and not growing.

Comment: What should happen if there are 2 occurrences of `pattern` less than `N` lines apart?  I think this would squash the previously found one before the associated line is printed.

Comment: @EricRenouf True, the original 'forwards' example misses those, so mine will too.  Edited to mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way with `sed`.

For *N=1*:

```
sed '$!N; /.*\n.*pattern/P; D' FILE
```

For *N=2*

```
sed '1N; $!N; /.*\n.*\n.*pattern/P; D' FILE
```

For the *N=2* case, the 1st line this will read the next *N-1* lines in the pattern space then start a `N;P;D` cycle - read another line in and if the last line in the pattern space matches, print the first line in the pattern space then delete it, starting a new cycle.

The downside is that it needs to be modified for different values of *N*:

For *N=3*:

```
sed '1{N;N}; $!N; /.*\n.*\n.*\n.*pattern/P; D' FILE
```

For *N=4*:

```
sed '1{N;N;N}; $!N; /.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*pattern/P; D' FILE
```

so it quickly becomes cumbersome though for greater values of *N* you could prepare a script file and pass it to `sed`.

Comment: @AlexHarvey - what's wrong with `infile` as an input file name?

Comment: Nothing, sorry. I see upper case used a lot in modern documentation (Python, Ruby's arg parser for instance). Not always. To me, a nice way to distinguish a placeholder string from a literal string. Shall I change it back?